# Different relationships on different model types Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I wonder how you'd go about my problem where I am going to display different types of events. For example 2 different events could be a soccer event and a formula1 event.

In these 2 scenarios there are different types of participants. In a soccer game this would be the 2 teams, and in a formular1 event it would be all the drivers.

Here are my Eloquent example of what I would like to do:

```
public function participants()
{
    if ($this->type == 'soccer_game') {
        return $this->hasMany(EventTeam::class);
    } else if ($this->type == 'formula1_race') {
        return $this->hasMany(EventDriver::class);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But when trying this and try to load it I get the error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()".

I think I need a push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use "Many To Many Polymorphic Relations", https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes just curious to know, how it is related to user's question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct approach would be to use [Many To Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) 
Example
**Step 1)** Create pivot table `eventables` with following structure 
**Note:** Change the data type of event_id and eventable_id to respective table's primary key

```
eventables
    event_id - integer  
    eventable_id - integer
    eventable_type - string
```

**Step 2)** Add `Event()` method to your EventTeam and EventDriver Models

```
public function events(){
    return $this->morphToMany(Event::class, 'eventable');
}
```

**Step 3)** Define inverse of above relationship in Event model

```
public function eventDrivers()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(EventDriver::class, 'eventable');
}

public function eventTeams()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(EventTeam::class, 'eventable');
}
```

Now, you can retrieve the different models on different event

Comment: But this would mean I need to call Event->eventTeams for soccer games and Event->eventDrivers for formula 1? I'd like to have them both under the participant method so I always can load the participants when loading the event using "$with = ['participants']".

Answer (score 0):

```
public function participants()
{
    if ($this->type == 'soccer_game') {
        return $this->hasMany(EventTeam::class);
    } else if ($this->type == 'formula1_race') {
        return $this->hasMany(EventDriver::class);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

In this case `return $this;` will return the instance of Model class and relations are expected to return HasOne, HasMany, BelongsToMany etc type of instances.

To resolve this the fallback relation must contain instance of any of these classes.

Comment: Yes I understand. But that should never occur since the type attribute should always exist. I just added it since the editor complained.

Comment: @JimmieJohansson you could always done something like return new HasMany; to mimic it instead or returning completely different class.